# Orientating app's view to landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation

`I've UIViewController and another UIView with some images and labels on it.`

I wanna change orientation and it works well, I can change **aqGridview frame** when rotating device,

My code :

```
    - (void)makePortraitOrientation { 
[gridView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 768,961)]; //works like a charm 
HeaderView* dsd = [[HeaderView alloc] initWithParentID:self]; // in this way there is no errors but nothing changes 
[dsd.label setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; 
[dsd setNeedsDisplay];
 [self.HeaderView.label setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; //error, no object HeaderView in UIViewController 
[self.HeaderView.label CGRectMake]
 }
```

> Header file of UIView

```
@interface HeaderView : UIView{
id parentID;

UIButton *menu;
UIImageView *icon;
NSString *product;
THLabel *label;
NSMutableArray *backs;
```

}

> The main problem is how can i change frames and places of images and
>   labels which is on another UIView, not in my UIViewController ?

All the views created programatically.

Comment: so u have a view controller and a sub view. U need to handle the frame of the subview frame while rotating. Am i right?

Comment: there is `@interface ViewController_ipad : UIViewController <AQGridViewDataSource, AQGridViewDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>`
AND ANOTHER VIEW`@interface HeaderView : UIView`

Comment: Your sub view is UIView only right?

Comment: Yeah, you can see how it's created from my upper comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on your controls frame you need to adjust the position of our controls while rotating the device. 
Access controls which is in our view controller like this. `[self.button setFrame:];`

Access the sub view controls frame like this: `[self.subviewname.control setFrame:];`

Based on the orientation you need to handle the frames. You can use auto re-sizing also.

Update:
Make sure **whether your sub view is added properly in your view controller** like this :

[self.view addSubView:self.mysubView];
**Increase the score of your sub view(HeaderView) as well.**

Comment: Thank you, but i can't access my subview by calling it like this:
`[self.HeaderView.control setFrame:]` it can't see my HeaderView. Property HeaderView not found on object type ViewController_ipad.

Comment: Update your question with your sub view creation and loading code.

Comment: Increase the scope of your sub view instance and try once,.

Comment: `[self.view addSubView:self.HeaderView];` it doesn't work, i am getting an error - property HeaderView not found on object of type
ViewController_ipad

Comment: You need to increase the scope of the header view.Declare it in .h file or in .m declaration part.

Comment: What do you mean ? all these two views are created in the same header file

Comment: In which view controller your are adding the HeaderView as a sub view?

Comment: i am adding in my UIViewController in ViewDidLoad method  
    `viewH = [[HeaderView alloc] initWithParentID:self];
    [self.view addSubview:viewH];`